# Convincing gcc to ignore system libraries in favour of locally installed libraries

Tags: linux, gcc, linker

I am trying to build a simple executable that uses boost_serialization and boost_iostreams.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/archive/xml_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/xml_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/filtering_stream.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/filter/gzip.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/device/file.hpp>

int main()
{
    using namespace boost::iostreams;
    filtering_ostream os;
    os.push(boost::iostreams::gzip_compressor());
    os.push(boost::iostreams::file_sink("emptyGzipBug.txt.gz"));
}
```

Unfortunately the system I am working with has a very outdated version of boost_serialization in /usr/lib/, and I have no way to change that.

I am fairly certain when I build the example using

```
g++ -o main main.cpp -lboost_serialization -lboost_iostreams
```

that the linker errors result because gcc uses the system version of boost_serialization rather than my locally installed version.  Setting LIBRARY_PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH to /home/andrew/install/lib doesnt work.  When i build using

```
g++ -o main main.cpp -L/home/andrew/install/lib -lboost_serialization -lboost_iostreams
```

then everything works.

My questions are:

1. How can I get gcc to tell me the filenames of the libraries its using?
2. Is it possible to setup the environment so that I dont have to specify the absolute path to my local boost on the command line of gcc.

Comment: You might miss some `-I` options to `g++` for your versions of "system" libraries (and you should pass `-Wall -g` to `g++` at first). You should use a builder like [GNU make](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/)

Comment: `-v` should give some info on paths to the folders it's looking at for include files.

Comment: `-v` tells me its looking for includes in the right place but doesnt tell me about library paths

Comment: "Is it possible to setup the environment so that I dont have to specify" This is possible. *Everything* is possible. You have the source code for the entire OS and development toolchain. However this is rather not recommended. Instead, *write a makefile*.

Answer (score 8):

PS After typing the below info, I thought I'd be kind and add what you need for your specific case:

```
g++ -Wl,-rpath,/home/andrew/install/lib -o main main.cpp -I/home/andrew/install/include -L/home/andrew/install/lib -lboost_serialization -lboost_iostreams
```

---

gcc itself doesn't care about the libraries. The linker does ;).
Even though the linker needs to find the shared libraries so it can resolve
symbols, it doesn't store the path of those libraries in the executable normally.

So, for a start, lets find out what is actually in the binary after you linked it:

```
$ readelf -d main | grep 'libboost'
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libboost_serialization.so.1.54.0]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libboost_iostreams.so.1.54.0]
```

Just the names thus.

The libraries that are actually used are detemined by /lib/ld-linux.so.*
at run time:

```
$ ldd main | grep libboost
        libboost_serialization.so.1.54.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_serialization.so.1.54.0 (0x00007fd8fa920000)
        libboost_iostreams.so.1.54.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_iostreams.so.1.54.0 (0x00007fd8fa700000)
```

The path is found by looking in /etc/ld.so.cache (which is normally
compiled by running ldconfig). You can print its contents with:

```
ldconfig -p | grep libboost_iostreams
    libboost_iostreams.so.1.54.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_iostreams.so.1.54.0
    libboost_iostreams.so.1.49.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/libboost_iostreams.so.1.49.0
    libboost_iostreams.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_iostreams.so
```

but since that is only the cached result of a previous look up,
you are more interested in the output of:

```
$ ldconfig -v 2>/dev/null | egrep '^[^[:space:]]|libboost_iostreams'
/lib/i386-linux-gnu:
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu:
/usr/local/lib:
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:
    libboost_iostreams.so.1.54.0 -> libboost_iostreams.so.1.54.0
/lib32:
/usr/lib32:
/lib:
/usr/lib:
    libboost_iostreams.so.1.49.0 -> libboost_iostreams.so.1.49.0
```

which shows the paths that it looked in before finding a result.
Note if you are linking a 64bit program and it would find a 32bit
library first (or visa versa) then that would be skipped as being
incompatible. Otherwise, the first one found is used.

The paths used to search are specified in /etc/ld.so.conf which is
read (usually at boot time, or after installing something new)
when running ldconfig as root.

However, precedence take paths specified as a colon separated list
of paths in the environment variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH.
For example, if I'd do:

```
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/tmp
$ cp /usr/lib/libboost_iostreams.so.1.49.0 /tmp/libboost_iostreams.so.1.54.0
$ ldd main | grep libboost_iostreams
    libboost_iostreams.so.1.54.0 => /tmp/libboost_iostreams.so.1.54.0 (0x00007f621add8000)
```

then it finds 'libboost_iostreams.so.1.54.0' in /tmp (even though it was a libboost_iostreams.so.1.49.0).

Note that you CAN hardcode a path in your executable by passing -rpath to
the linker:

```
$ unset LD_LIBRARY_PATH
$ g++ -Wl,-rpath,/tmp -o main main.cpp -lboost_serialization -lboost_iostreams
$ ldd main | grep libboost_iostreams
    libboost_iostreams.so.1.54.0 => /tmp/libboost_iostreams.so.1.54.0 (0x00007fbd8bcd8000)
```

which can be made visible with

```
$ readelf -d main | grep RPATH
 0x000000000000000f (RPATH)              Library rpath: [/tmp]
```

Note that LD_LIBRARY_PATH even takes precedence over -rpath, unless
you also passed -Wl,--disable-new-dtags, along with the -rpath and provided that you are linking an executable and your linker supports
this flag.

You can show the search paths that gcc uses during compile(link) time with the -print-search-dirs command line option:

```
$ g++ -print-search-dirs  | grep libraries
libraries: =/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../../lib/:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../:/lib/:/usr/lib/
```

This can be influenced by adding -L command line options. If a library can't be found in a path specified with the -L option then it looks in paths found through the environment variable GCC_EXEC_PREFIX (see the man page for that) and if that fails it uses the environment variable LIBRARY_PATH.

When you run g++ with the -v option, it will print the LIBRARY_PATH used.

```
LIBRARY_PATH=/tmp/lib g++ -v -o main main.cpp -lboost_serialization -lboost_iostreams 2>&1 | grep LIBRARY_PATH
LIBRARY_PATH=/tmp/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../../lib/:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/../lib/:/tmp/lib/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../:/lib/:/usr/lib/
```

Finally, note that especially for boost (but in general) you should
use header files that match the correct version! So, if the library that you
link with at run time is version xyz you should have used an -I command line option to get g++ to find the corresponding header files, or things might not link or worse, result in unexplainable crashes.

Comment: Note that the compile-time linker doesn't look for the SO_NAME (which is shown by readelf). Using -lfoo it looks for libfoo.so. Therefore **in the LIBRARY_PATH path there much be a libfoo.so** that points to the real library, which has it's SO_NAME hardcoded inside it. If the SO_NAME (used during runtime linking) is different from that file name then you need another symbolic link to make the run time linker find it!). Ie, if the SO_NAME is libfoo.so.1 and the file name is libfoo.so.1.4 then you need a symlink from libfoo.so.1 to libfoo.so.1.4 for things to work during run time ;).

Answer (score 0):

-nodefaultlibs

```
       Do not use the standard system libraries when linking.  Only the
       libraries you specify are passed to the linker, and options
       specifying linkage of the system libraries, such as
       -static-libgcc or -shared-libgcc, are ignored.  The standard
       startup files are used normally, unless -nostartfiles is used.

       The compiler may generate calls to "memcmp", "memset", "memcpy"
       and "memmove".  These entries are usually resolved by entries in
       libc.  These entry points should be supplied through some other
       mechanism when this option is specified.
```

Haven't used it myself but it sounds exactly like what was asked for.